# php not writes to a php file <?php ?> signs and $variable

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm having a problem in creating php file with php. Php not writes php  signs and $variable.

ex:

```
    <?php
$txt = "<?php $passwords = array(
    'login1' => 'password1',
    'login2' => 'password2',
    'login3' => 'password3',
);?>";
$myfile = fopen("htpassw_array.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

it prints me out to htpassw_array.php file:

```
 = array(
    'login1' => 'password1',
    'login2' => 'password2',
    'login3' => 'password3',
);
```

missing `<?php ?>` and `$variable` signs.

How to do it?
Thank You.

Comment: The missing `$passwords` is easy to explain, it's trying to interpolate that variable into the string. But the `<?php` should definitely be written, there's no reason it wouldn't be. But for all that is holy, don't manually write PHP files! Dump your data as JSON or something. If you absolutely need it in PHP format, at least use `var_export`. This is all very fishy to begin with.

Comment: as stated above, its better to save data as json or var_export, but if you really have to save as php file, then you can try to escape (e.g.: backslash) or concat the string (e.g.: "<"."?php".)

Comment: @Kristian What would the concat be necessary for? This isn't a `<script` in Javascript, PHP doesn't double-interpret itself…

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comment by deceze, its better to save your data in JSON format or var_export format rather than as php file. Maybe the OP thought that if it's saved in such format then it will be accessible from webserver root (e.g.: point your browser's address bar to `https://example.com/htpassw_array.json` will download the whole password, while point your browser's address bar to `https://example.com/htpassw_array.php` will only give you an empty page).

The solution is to save the JSON file outside webserver root path (e.g.: in /home/youruser or C:/Users/youruser).

Example:

```php
<?php
$password = array(
    'login1' => 'password1',
    'login2' => 'password2',
    'login3' => 'password3',
);
$myfile = fopen("/home/myuser/htpassw_array.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, json_encode($password));
fclose($myfile);
```

Of course, the best option is to use a database (e.g.: mysql, postgres).

Then again, there is some use for php code to generate other php code (e.g.: writing CRUD generator). To prevent special commands/expressions to be interpreted, you can try:

1. escaping them (e.g.: backslash): `$txt = "<?php \$passwords = array(`
2. separating them into more piece of string: `$txt = "<?php "."$"."passwords = array(`
3. switch double quote and single quote to prevent php from interpreting `$passwords`
4. or create a template then using string replace on them (this is an overkill in your use case)

Also, as deceze stated in comment, `PHP doesn't double-interpret itself`, so number 2 is not needed in this case

Example solution no 1 (escaping)

```php
<?php
$txt = "<?php \$passwords = array(
    'login1' => 'password1',
    'login2' => 'password2',
    'login3' => 'password3',
); ?>";
$myfile = fopen("htpassw_array.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Example solution no 2 (concatenating)

```php
<?php
$txt = "<?php "."$"."passwords = array(
    'login1' => 'password1',
    'login2' => 'password2',
    'login3' => 'password3',
); ?>";
$myfile = fopen("htpassw_array.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Example solution no 3 (double/single quote)

```php
<?php
$txt = '<?php $passwords = array(
    "login1" => "password1",
    "login2" => "password2",
    "login3" => "password3",
); ?>';
$myfile = fopen("htpassw_array.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Output file:

```
<?php $passwords = array(
    'login1' => 'password1',
    'login2' => 'password2',
    'login3' => 'password3',
); ?>
```

When I run:

```php
<?php
require_once("htpassw_array.php");
var_dump($passwords);
```

The output is:

```
array(3) {
  ["login1"]=>
  string(9) "password1"
  ["login2"]=>
  string(9) "password2"
  ["login3"]=>
  string(9) "password3"
}
```